# CSS Table collapse on browser resize

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation that is styled using css tables to ensure all cells are distributed evenly. My problem is that when I resize my browser, the Nav collapses left and doesnt function properly, any ideass?

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav { width: 500px; overflow: hidden; }
nav ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 100%; display: table; }
nav ul li { display: table-cell; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zbLwg/

**UPDATE**

It seems that some of my javascript is causing this conflict, sorry for wasting anybodys time that tried helping me solve this

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm unable to recreate using the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE

Comment: all of those, testing browser wide... I have a couple js resize functions that have the menu linked in so Im currently debugging to see if that has any effect

Comment: I'm not able to recreate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean that if you make the browser really really small it doesn't work properly? The nav has a width of 500px so the ul won't get smaller than that if you set its width to 100%.

Use javascript or set the nav width relative to its parent using a given percentage.

Comment: no its responsive thats not the issue. When I resize the browser even a pixel eg 1100px resized to 1099px the cells collapse

Comment: Oh great! Then I can't figure out what's happening.